# Win7 app to monitor bandwidth capacity over time?

Tags: bandwidth

I see lots of questions about bandwidth usage, but that's not my issue.

I suspect my ISPs quality of service deteriorates/is altered intentionally on a regular schedule, but need some data logging to prove it.

Ideally, I'd like an app for Win7 that will sit unobtrusively in my systray and run an internet speed test at a configurable interval, saving the results to a logfile for later analysis. Like how there are websites you can visit (ex: DSLReports) but automated and at a set interval in the background.

You Linux guys are probably laughing about how you could code one up in a few seconds, but alas, I lack such skill.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yea it is do'able in a fairly short amount of time and a server of your own.. I mean. I never heard of such a programme. but I can make one in a day or two (windows service and all that, with reports)

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if there isn't something like this already, speedtest.net USED to do one (was just an .exe to run - back in modem days) and i remember a BT one that was built into their ISDN software I previously used for multi-linking which just worked from commandline... Schedule etc :)

Comment: The problem with these tools is that bandwidth is shared. E.g. if your computer has malware that sends out spam, such tool will show decreased bandwidth, while in fact the available bandwidth is only decreased to that bandwidth measuring tool, as large amount of available bandwidth is consumed by some other process.

Comment: I bet it deteriorates when people get home from work and load Netflix.

Answer (score 1):

[Came across this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/download_speed_tester.html) tool, totally untested, yet i've used other utilities from the website with great success so happy to recommend it.

There is a section about Commandline options & reporting so it would be very easy to write a script/batch file to run it with these and then just use Scheduled Tasks to run it periodically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're located in France (*), you can use [Grenouille](http://grenouille.com/index.php) (I am not sure if it's possible to use outside France). It's free but it used to under-assess my bandwidth when I was using it a few years ago. Note that both the website and software are in French.

(*) http://grenouille.com/ma_grenouille/modify.php says:

> Ami(e)s belges, suisses ou québecois (et autres pays francophones) :
>   grenouille.com n'est disponible qu'en France pour le moment, un
>   déploiement vers d'autres pays est prévu mais ce n'est pas pour tout
>   de suite... :-)

In English: not available outside France.